# Stopping form submitting interception

Tags: jquery

I have the code below:

```
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    ...
```

Then every form submitted is intercepted.

**My question**: how can I stop this interception?

Thanks.

Comment: I need this function at a specific moment. After that moment, I need to avoid the form submitting to be catched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) should do the trick.

```
$('form', dialog).unbind("submit");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return false;` in the end of your function like this:

```
function(){ 
    /* Some code */

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), try adding `return true;` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$('form', dialog).submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
```

`event.preventDefault()`  If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

or you can simply use:

```
 $('form', dialog).submit(function (e) {
    //your code here 
    return false;
   }
```